# cant open the dialer from my app in react native version 0.63 in Xiaomi Poco X3

Tags: android, react-native

I have application that write in react native version 0.63
i have this code

```
Linking.canOpenURL('tel:phoneNumber')
      .then(supported => {
         if (supported) {
            Linking.openURL('tel:phoneNumber');
         }
        else{
            alert(‘not working’)
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        alert(‘exception not working’)
      });
```

i replace the phoneNumber with the phone number of user
this code working fine in all devices i checked android and iphone
but in this phone Xiaomi Poco X3 is not worked
i get supported = false
i do not why
thank you for every one

I try to open the dialer from my app in android and iphone
this is working in a lot of devices but in specific device (Xiaomi Poco X3) is not working